# Is it unsafe to store derived object to void*, then cast base object out of it?

Tags: c++, inheritance

For example:

```
class Base1 {};
class Base2 {};
class Derived: publid Base1, public Base2 {};

// object is stored on a void* slot
void* void_slot = new Derived();

// ... many decades after ...

//object is fetched from the void* slot
Base2* obj = (Base2*) void_slot;
obj->some_base2_method();
```

I think it is probably unsafe. Does `dynamic_cast<>` solve this issue?

```
Base2* obj = dynamic_cast<Base2*> void_slot;
```

**More backgrounds**:

I'm working on calling C++ library from Perl. When you construct an C++ object, it is stored in the integer slot of a Perl value (the `IV` value of a `SV`), which is like a `void*`; and when you call methods, the object pointer is cast from `IV`, and the corresponding C++ method is called using the object pointer. Thus I guess it could be problematic, as the pointer to base type can be different with the pointer to derived type, especially when there are multiple inheritance.

I've posted a similar question on PerlMonks, but did not get much response from there. So I ask it here, from the aspect of C++.

Comment: No, not safe in general.  Csn be safe in onr particular compiler with particular objects (think layout compatible, plus reasonable assumptions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is unsafe, but will probably cause no errors in your example due to the [empty base optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo). Consider instead the following example:

```
class Base1 { int b1; };
class Base2 { int b2; };
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 { int d; };
```

The memory layout for an object of type `Derived` will probably look like this:

```
0123456789AB   
[b1][b2][ d]
^ begin of Derived
^ begin of Base1
    ^ begin of Base2
```

Now, a pointer to `Derived` and to `Base1` will have the same numerical value, but one to `Base2` will be different. To change the numerical value appropriately, the compiler has to know that you are converting a `Derived*` to a `Base2*`. This is not possible when casting it to `void*` in between, since the value of the `void*` could just as well have come from a `Base2*`.

In fact, a conversion sequence like `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(x))` is exactly how `reinterpret_cast<T*>(x)` is defined. And you would not assume that `reinterpret_cast` is safe to randomly use an arbitrary types - would you?

#### What about dynamic_cast?

While one might believe that `dynamic_cast` might help here, it is in fact not even applicable! Since `dynamic_cast` is supposed to use run time type information to guarantee that a cast is possible, its target needs to be a pointer (or reference) to a class type with at least one virtual member. In this case, the target is not even a pointer to a *complete* type, but to `void`.

#### How to deal with the conundrum?

No matter what you do afterwards you *must* retrieve the same type of pointer that you stored (with a sole exception for interpreting your object as a `char` array). The obvious solution would be, to either always store a pointer to a common base class like

```
void* void_slot = static_cast<CommonBase*>(input);
CommonBase* output = static_cast<CommonBase*>(void_slot);
```

or to use an intermediate class that knows which kind of pointer you are talking about

```
struct Slotty {
    enum class type_t {
        Base1,
        Base2,
        Derived
    } type;
    void* ptr;

    Slotty(Base1* ptr) : type(type_t::Base1), ptr(ptr) { }
    Slotty(Base2* ptr) : type(type_t::Base2), ptr(ptr) { }
    Slotty(Derived* ptr) : type(type_t::Derived), ptr(ptr) { }
};

void* void_slot = static_cast<void*>(new Slotty(input));
Slotty* temp = static_cast<Slotty*>(void_slot);
switch(Slotty.type) {
    case Slotty::type_t::Base1:
        /* do sth with */ static_cast<Base1*>(temp.ptr);
        break;
    case Slotty::type_t::Base2:
        /* do sth with */ static_cast<Base2*>(temp.ptr);
        break;
    case Slotty::type_t::Derived:
        /* do sth with */ static_cast<Derived*>(temp.ptr);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking about `dynamic_cast` in my question. I cannot use `static_cast`, because the object in `void*` slot could be something other like `Derived2`.

Comment: @jiandingzhe If you have a `void*` to something you do not know the exact type of, you are basically screwed.

Comment: I can only suppose the void* stores some object derived from the base class, but cannot ensure which exact class it is. How can I safely call a base method from it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have complete control over your classes, just create a single virtual root base. Cast to that first before you cast to `void *`, then cast back to that first. Then you can use `dynamic_cast` to cast to whatever derived type you want:

```
struct Root {
    virtual ~Root() {}
};

struct Base1 : virtual public Root { };
struct Base2 : virtual public Root { };
struct Derived1 : public Base1, public Base2 { };
struct Derived2 : public Derived1 { };

int main() {

    Derived1 *d1 = new Derived1;
    Derived2 *d2 = new Derived2;

    void *vp = static_cast<Root *>(d1);
    Derived1 *d11 = dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(static_cast<Root *>(vp));
    vp = static_cast<Root *>(d2);
    Derived2 *d22 = dynamic_cast<Derived2 *>(static_cast<Root *>(vp));

    delete d1;
    delete d2;
}
```

EDIT: Apparently the classes must be polymorphic and you must use dynamic_cast, so put a trivial virtual destructor in Root.